# Frozen screen while selecting wifi network

Tags: networking, wayland, window-manager, usability

I use Ubuntu 22.04, in the default window manager when I click on "select network" the window of the network manager occupies the center of the screen and there I can pick one of the available wifi, however the rest of the screen is grayed out and I cannot access other programs or switch  to other windows running at the same time. It is impossible to start other programs too. Why and how to fix this behavior? Thank you